# Infinite integral that seems to diverge but question requires it does not.

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

The formula for half space solutions to the Laplace equation can be given:
\begin{equation}
u(x,y) = \int_{z\in \mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{(x-z)^2+y^2}f(z)
\end{equation}

Use this formula to solve the initial value problem: 
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2u=0. \quad u(x,0)=f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{equation}
Now I have gotten the integral into the form (as a hint in the question asks):
\begin{equation}
\int_{z\in \mathbb{R}}\frac{a(z-x)+b}{(z-x)^2+y^2} + \frac{cz+d}{1+z^2}
\end{equation}
Where a,b,c,d do not depend on z.
But have been unable to compute this integral. Wolfram Alpha says the integral diverges. The integral can be Lebesgue integration. Any hints/similar eamples would be great,thanks.

Comment: What values did you get for $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: @uniquesolution they were very complicated but only depended on x,y. I added that to the question there.

Comment: @PierreCarre we derived the formula in class and the next question is to discuss why the formula doesn't verify the initial conditions, the main point of the question was to compute the integral, I believe.

Comment: Convergence follows if $a=c=0$, for which your integral is $$\int_{\Bbb R}\left(\frac{b}{(z-x)^2+y^2}+\frac{d}{1+z^2}\right)dz=\pi\left(\frac{b}{y}+d\right).$$ More general values of $a,\,c$ make cancelling contributions if we integrate them respectively on  $[x-k,\,x+k],\,[-k,\,k]$.

Comment: @PierreCarre This is the [Poisson kernel for the upper-half plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel), so it it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\begin{equation}
u(x,y) = \int_{z\in \mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{(x-z)^2+y^2}f(z)\\=
\int_{z\in \mathbb{R}}\frac{a(z-x)+b}{(z-x)^2+y^2}dz+
\int_{z\in \mathbb{R}}\frac{cz+d}{1+z^2}dz\\
=I_1+I_2
\end{equation}$$
Free CAS MAXIMA says that principal values of integrals is
$$I_1=\frac{y\, \left( {{y}^{2}}+{{x}^{2}}-1\right) }{\left( {{y}^{2}}-2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) \, \left( {{y}^{2}}+2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) }$$
$$I_2=-\frac{{{y}^{2}}-{{x}^{2}}-1}{\left( {{y}^{2}}-2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) \, \left( {{y}^{2}}+2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) }$$
Then final integral is
$$u=I_1+I_2=\frac{y+1}{{{y}^{2}}+2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1}$$

Answer (score -2):

Solve
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0, \;-\infty<x<\infty,\; y>0,$$
$$u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2},\quad u_y(x,0)=0,\;-\infty<x<\infty.$$
I get 
$$u=\frac{{{x}^{2}}-{{y}^{2}}+1}{\left( {{y}^{2}}-2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) \, \left( {{y}^{2}}+2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) }$$
**Solving hint:**
General solution of Laplace equation is
$$u=F(x+iy)+G(x-iy)$$
**Question:**
How depends the solution from condition on $u_y(x,0)$ ?

For example if $u_y(x,0)=1$, solution is
$$u=\frac{{{y}^{5}}+2 {{x}^{2}}\, {{y}^{3}}-2 {{y}^{3}}-{{y}^{2}}+{{x}^{4}} y+2 {{x}^{2}} y+y+{{x}^{2}}+1}{\left( {{y}^{2}}-2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) \, \left( {{y}^{2}}+2 y+{{x}^{2}}+1\right) }$$

Comment: This doesn't address the main question: How to use the given integral formula to compute the solution?